# Restore only some volumes from a multiOS system image

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, system-restore, windows-7-restore

I have two Windows installations on different drives. System Restore won't let me make a system image of only the one I use most (Win7), I had to make a system image for **both** drives.

I recently had to restore because of an OS boot failure. I noticed that the restore wizard from the win 7 disk restores **all** drives and the specified ones there in the box can not be changed.

Why is that if only one's the problem?
Is there a way to **restore only individual drives** from the system image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 'Why is that?': Call Microsoft and ask them. There is no way for us to answer that.

2) If system restore does not allow that then use a different program. Preferably one where you do not need to boot from a harddisk.

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) can boot from a CD or a USB pendrive and is free. There are also many other porgrams which can do this, e.g. [Acronis TrueImage](http://www.acronis.co.uk/homecomputing/products/trueimage/), Symantec/Norton Ghost, ...

In your specific case:

- Make a new backup from the drive which you want to keep.
- Restore both drives using the windows solution
- Restore the drive you wanted to keep from the CloneZilla backup.

Comment: Thank you for the applications provided, I just didn't know that much of back-ups and system restores. And thanks for the edit. 
P.S. 'There is no way for us to answer that.' I just wanted to say how disappointed I am of MS :D.

Comment: MS provides a free tool which works for most of their user base. That is their goal / their way of making profit. It is not to provide solution for everything without increasing the cost of the base OS.

Comment: I am not mad at Microsoft, I'm not going to destroy the company, I'm just saying, JESUS, GUYS, TAKE IT EASY!! MS FTW! What is with all the criticism? I am sorry for mentioning Microsoft in this site, I am going to write a sorry letter to the company because if they find out what I said they are probably going to sue me and put me behind bars for the rest of my life..